# Textures turn black in material and render mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

I downloaded a free shader setup from a site and after unwrapping it, the texture comes fine in the texture shading viewport. But when I shift to Material, or render shading, the object is just plain black. I cannot seem to understand where the mistake is. I am using cycles render.

When I tried using an another random image texture, there was no problem. I could see the texture in all modes. So idk where I am going wrong with this shader.

Edit: Sorry for being so vague. So I am using Blender Cycles v2.78. I downloaded a wood shader from a site called Chocofur, with the node setup as attached. This is how it looks in Texture Shading.

[image]

The node setup:

[image]

However, when I go to material, or rendered shading, this is how it turns out.
[image]

[image]

Now just to check whether I was doing something wrong, I used a plain image as a texture in one of them, and it seemed to appear fine both in material and render shading. 
[image]

So I am guessing there is something within the shaders settings.The thing in red in the node setup is probably the problem since it says something isn't defined. I am not very thorough with using nodes and maybe that's why I can't figure it out. I hope I've been clearer this time. Let me know if I need to attach the blend file for reference.

Comment: And how are we supposed to answer your question with such little information? Add at least a screenshot of your shader setup. Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) thoroughly and add more information by using the edit link below your question.

Comment: The node group marked red and named "undefined" is likely a node type which was defined by an addon, which is now inactive/not installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a newer version of blender.

You can't use the Principled BSDF shader in versions previous to [2.79](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.79)
.

Comment: I see..that might be the problem. Thank you, will check it out in the newer version.